# sum of primes under 2000000

Tags: c++

I'm trying this program to find the sum of all the primes under two million, but for some reason I am coming up with a number far below what I should be expecting.

Here is my code. A co-working says I might not be catching all the primes with my program but he doesn't know C++ and I don't see how I could be missing them.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 500000;
    int e = 0;

    // this is an array to hold all the prime number i find,
    // it's initialized to the arbitrarily high number of 500000
    int list[a]; 

    //here i am initializing the first members of my list to the first primes
    list[0] = 2; 
    list[1] = 3;
    list[2] = 5;
    a = 3; // i set a = 3 to catch the next coming prime of 7
    for (int c = 5; c < 2000000; c++)
    {
        // this bool is for prime catching, 
        // if d is false then the number will not be saved into the array
        bool d = false; 

        // this bool is for an exit statement in the following iterative loop, 
        // if it's false the loop will exit
        bool h = true; 
        for (int i = 0; list[i] < c/2 + 1 && h == true; i++)
        {
            // this checks to see if a number is evenly 
            // divisable by any of my primes so far
            if (c % list[i] == 0) 
            {
                d = false;
                h = false;
            }
        }
        if (d == true)
        {
            list[a] = c; // if i find a prime i save it into my array
            e += c; // if i find a prime i sum it to my total
            a++;
        }
    }
    cout << e; 
}
```

Comment: Project Euler problem? Check out the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_eratosthenes). It's very fast at generating primes up to a certain point, 10 million I believe.

Comment: @Marlom Indeed, problem 10.

Comment: It looks like you're doing the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) the hard way.

Comment: Aside from anything else, the correct answer is greater than `INT_MAX` for any normal C++ implementation, so you cannot compute it in an `int`. Try `long long`.

Comment: @steve jessop  thank you, that is exactly what i needed to do, besides that i had to (thanks to david schwartz) set e to 5 (2+3) (not 10)and set d back to true, i don't know why i put it at false. but i am getting the correct answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d` is always and forever false. No code ever sets it to `true`.

Also, you need to start `e` at 10 (2 + 3 + 5).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    bool prime;
    int num = 200000;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=3; i<=num; i++){
        prime = true;
        for(int j=2; j<=i/2; j++){
            if(i%j == 0) prime = false;
        }
        if(prime) sum+=i;
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: Technically this works, but there are much more efficient ways. [This youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbg3ZX2pWlgKZ0eR9lviOkeagDuSPl89K) is a great resource for understanding prime numbers and how to find them efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the most effective way to find if number is prime is to:

- Check if number is less than 4 (`<=3`), then it is prime number. Assuming only positive-integers participate.
- Otherwise, check if it is even number - then it is not a prime number.
- If more than 3, and is not even - check it against all number from 3 to square-root of given number, skipping all evens in check. If it is multiple of any number, then it is not prime. Otherwise it is prime.

In C++ words:

```
bool IsPrime(unsigned int nCheck)
{
   assert(nCheck>0);

   if(nCheck<=3)
     return true;

   if(nCheck%2==0)
     return false;

   for(int nCounter = 3; nCounter <= sqrt(nCheck); nCounter += 2) // Skip evens
   {
       if(nCheck % nCounter == 0)
          return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Any number is by 1 to square-root of that number. For example, 100, is divisible by max 10. Even it is divisible by, say 50, it is also divisible by 5. So, just check from 1 to 10.